# How to select font awesome class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, fonts, font-awesome

I have this code;

```
      <div id="blok1" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div id="img1 "i class="fa fa-pencil fa-3x"></i>
```

I want to animate the width and the height of the i class but I can't get it to work.

This is how my jquery code looks like:

```
  $('#img1').click(function() {
    $('.fa fa-pencil fa-3x')
    //code
  });
```

This doesn't work for me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The HTML you posted is invalid. Did you mean `<i id="img1" class="fa fa-pencil fa-3x"></i>`?

Comment: `$('i.fa.fa-pencil.fa-3x')`

Answer (score 2):

Fixing your HTML...

```
<div id="blok1" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<i id="img1" class="fa fa-pencil fa-3x"></i>
```

And for your selector, [combine the classes](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) like so:

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    $('.fa.fa-pencil.fa-3x')
    //code
});
```